# How to link a pdf file in ePub 3?

Tags: pdf, ios7, ibooks, epub3

i'm developing an ePub using [Sigil](https://code.google.com/p/sigil/).

I have addedd some PDF file in my **Misc** Folder.

Now i've created a link to that file, and everything is working fine with iBooks on my Mac.

But on iBooks for iOS7 when i tap the link it load (in overlay) a gray page, is this a bug?

Should i use another way for link the PDF?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same. I'll be interested by your epub. I'm not on mac and it looks like all my readers don't like linking a pdf. So if you succeeded I'd like to compare your solution with mine to see what's different.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue with iBooks for mac not really requiring strict ePub code. Many times things that "work" in iBooks for mac aren't actually compliant at all. I can't speak for Sigil directly, but can help with the ePub itself: I am guessing you need to change some things in your .opf file: you need to include the pdf as an item in your manifest AND as a nonlinear page in your spine: , .

You should use ePubcheck (https://github.com/IDPF/epubcheck) to make sure you are exporting a valid ePub.

If you need a tool to zip/unzip your ePub I would use this: http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=55681

Good luck!